# how to upload file and store the path in database using struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have been trying to do this task but not able to succeed. I can upload file which can store in "C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\work" but i don't know how to store the path in database.  here is my code.

```
package com.rajesh.action;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.IOException; 

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class UploadFile extends ActionSupport{
private File myFile;
private String myFileContentType;
private String myFileFileName;
private String destPath;

public String execute()
{
/* Copy file to a safe location */
destPath = "C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/upload";

try{
System.out.println("Src File name: " + myFile);
System.out.println("Dst File name: " + myFileFileName);

File destFile  = new File(destPath, myFileFileName);
FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destFile);

}catch(IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
return ERROR;
}

return SUCCESS;
}

public File getMyFile() {
  return myFile;
}
public void setMyFile(File myFile) {
  this.myFile = myFile;
}
public String getMyFileContentType() {
  return myFileContentType;
}
public void setMyFileContentType(String myFileContentType) {
  this.myFileContentType = myFileContentType;
}
public String getMyFileFileName() {
  return myFileFileName;
}
public void setMyFileFileName(String myFileFileName) {
  this.myFileFileName = myFileFileName;
}
}
```

and here is my jsp to upload file.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Struts 2 - Login Application | ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Struts 2 - Login Application</h2>
<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="login" method="post">
<s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
<s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20" />
<s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
value="false" />
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
value="ApplicationResources" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
<action name="login" class="com.rajesh.action.LoginAction">
<result name="success">admin.jsp</result>
<result name="error">loginstruts.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="upload" class="com.rajesh.action.UploadFile">
<result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
<result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

please help me out, i am new this struts2, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which framework you were using in dao layer? Hibernate or JPA

Comment: i am using jdbc and i am not using any hibernate or JPA. The action is controlled by struts2.

Comment: @RajeshAcharya So, how would you like to use JDBC with the action is controlled by struts2?

Comment: i do not know much about struts2. but let me clarify this. i have struts.xml where it says like if success comes it has to redirect to some jsp page and my action class is doing all the upload thing and i do not have any DAO class, so what right now i have is one jsp page which is front end and one struts xml and one action class. thats it sir.

Comment: It's not different from storing a `String` in a DB. Please edit your question to eliminate all noise about file upload completely unrelated to the concrete problem of storing a `String` in a DB. You have already solved the part of uploading a file and saving it. Your current only problem is storing a `String` in DB.

Comment: yes, you  are right. but do not know how to store the path in DB.

Answer (score 1):

After uploading file into your destination path write database logic in your action or you can create DAO class to connect database and insert records into it and use that class in struts action..You need to place database connection code after this line of your code..

**FileUtils.copyFile(myFile, destFile);**

sample code:

```
//To be write after above line in your action class
String filePathToStoreInDB = destPath+"\\"+myFileFileName;
MyDAO myDAO = new MyDAO();
String result = myDAO.insertRecord(filePathToStoreInDB);
if(result.equals("success")){
//proceed your logic
}else{
//your logic to display errro message
}

//logic in DAO class to insert record
public class MyDAO{
//Your code to insert record in database
return "success"; //if record inserted successfully
retrun "fail"; //if record failed to insert
}
}
```

Note: you can take column type in database as Varchar2 or Varchar depends on your requirement.